# The best way to abstract a JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to abstract away any given JavaScript framework (jQuery, MooTools etc.), that sits on the bottom of the framework stack? Essentially, I would like to have a situation where I could swap out the library, do changes only to one layer of the framework (not to every module, for example), and the whole thing could be up and running again.

So, every module should call a framework function(s), which would then be routed to the library.

Comment: Seems like your library is going to be very big

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to use something like the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Create your own interface, exposing the methods that you will be using in your application, and then create an adapter for each toolkit that you would like to support (jQuery, MooTools, YUI, etc). Your own interface would then route the method calls to the specific adapters.

If you were to support a new toolkit, all you'd have to do is to write a new adapter that translates methods from your own interface, to the methods of the specific toolkit.

This is something that [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/) currently does. You can choose which adapter to use (jQuery, YUI, etc) behind the method calls of the framework. For example: `Ext.getCmp()` would use the `jQuery.$()` when using the jQuery adapter. However, it is often not a very easy one-to-one mapping.

> Ext JS started its life as an extension to the Yahoo UI javascript library. At that time, Ext relied on YUI for all of its low-level cross-browser code. Now that Ext is a standalone JavaScript library, you have the choice of substituting YUI for other JavaScript libraries such as Prototype, or jQuery. The source files that map the low-level Ext API around other JavaScript libraries (or Ext's own base library) are known as adapters and they live in the source/adapter subdirectory. When you include Ext in your website you choose which adapter you want to use.
>
> From: [Ext JS Manual: Source Overview](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual:Ext_Source_Overview#Adapters)

Comment: How would this work really though? Given that the frameworks have a different set of methods and abilities, how would you write one all-encompassing super set of methods?  It seems like you'd have to fill in the gaps, every feature that one library has that another doesn't...you'd have to add the functionality where it's missing.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, you're right. I'm not saying it's easy... It's what ExtJS does however. It requires that you choose an adapter. Originally it supported YUI, jQuery, Prototype IIRC, but then they also implemented their own adapter. The good thing is that if you were using their own adapter, but then you'd want to use something that depends on jQuery, you could just switch the adapter. Very neat, but definitely not easy to implement.

Comment: @Daniel - That's my main point..it's not easy, and *how* "not easy" is a major factor here, I can't imagine it being less work than porting your code when needed.  Another reason to *really* stay away from this is the OP is targeting mobile devices with slower processors and connections, making this extra layer that much less attractive.  Heavier, more processor intensive and probably more work than porting in the first place...I stand by my strong recommendation to stay away from this altogether, *especially* for this particular application.

Comment: @Nick: I fully agree. My answer was just an attempt to answer the question, especially since I could relate to how Ext JS have tackled it. However, while I could see some advantages in Ext's case, this does not apply for the vast majority of applications. One major drawback, apart for the added complexity, is that you would not be able to exploit particular features of one toolkit, if the same feature is not offered by the others.

Comment: Just to share my experiences. Direct call to mootools getElement ($) vs. sandbox->adapter->mootools resulted to, on average, from 0.40ms vs. 0.95ms (tested with worst case scenario; low end Nokia device, whereas Android devices doesn't really seem to care about the implementation). Even though the execution time increase in percentages was quite high, when you look at the numbers by themselves, we are still under one millisecond per call, which is minuscule compared to the fact that the framework is now library agnostic.

Answer (score 6):

This would be writing a library for...libraries, if you are concerned about performance at all (and why *wouldn't* you be?) you should go a different route altogether.  Another abstraction layer on top of libraries with *very* different approaches (especially when you get into utilities, animations, etc.) would be very, *very* inefficient and time consuming.

No kidding, it'd take you less time to port your code several times even in any decent size project before building (or more importantly, maintaining) a library abstraction layer like this would.

Comment: @nick, there's a profound difference between toolkits/libraries and frameworks. Frameworks are build on top of toolkits and libraries. jQuery and Prototype are nothing more then toolkits, Dojo, Yui and are nearly frameworks and ExtJS can definatly be called a framework.

Comment: @BGerrissen - It depends on your definition I suppose, with jQuery + jQuery UI added on, how do you call that a toolkit and YUI a framework?  I think that's a grey area at best, it's really a question of core vs plugins and where the weight is IMO.

Comment: I am indeed, concerned about the performance, since most of this will be run in mobile devices. However, I am thiking of caching the hell out of the library requests, so that the framework could have direct references to the functions within the library, so that the request doesn't have to travel every time, through every layer.

Comment: @nick, No actually it's not a grey area... It's pretty well defined in software architecture world. View http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=zakas-architecture of Nicholas C. Zakas, specially catered for JS devs..

Comment: + the problem with porting is that you lose possibility to quickly and/or easily test out different libraries. Currently we are using Mootools, and we already have over 60 calls to library itself. And this is just a barebones prototype. Thus, when we start racking up modules, I would like them to be library independent, so that we don't end up into porting hell, when/if the time comes. Specially, as we would like to be as agile as possible.

Comment: @BGerrissen The framework in question is actually based on Nic Zakas's slides. :)

Comment: @crappish - Do you plan to change frameworks often? :) I just don't see that situation arise much at all, and with mobile I think you'd be concerned with caching, number of requests and overall CPU used, which *will* be greater with another layer on top.

Comment: @BGerrissen - I'm curious as to how you define jQuery UI in toolkit vs framework?  It's all JavaScript, and various components (that depend on the core libraries respectively) can be written in the same component ways...which goes back to my point, it's where the weight is.  If you can do *everything* that YUI does in a plugin, widget, etc, isn't it just a question of where the weight lies?

Comment: Yes, those (caching and requests) are concerns but there are already solutions in place for those. :) Overall CPU usage is a concern, specially for slower devices, but I am willing to sacrifice a small percentage of speed, if it gives me greater flexibility with the libraries. And yes, we have already tested out few libraries, all of which have bloat on top of them (IE6 for example, which is not a problem in mobile environment). The "bolt-on" library feature would allow us to easily benchmark different solutions and libraries, and even build somewhat custom framework.

Comment: @nick, watch the vid ;) Nicholas explains it better than I can.

Comment: The point is to be able to port the bottom layers without rewriting all the code on the top...switching frameworks doesn't happen often, but when it does, I like having code that's abstracted away the messy details. If you're concerned about performance, you could always compile/inline those functions you're using.

Comment: @omouse - "you could always compile/inline those functions you're using", that means you're editing the underlying library to get there...which is totally against the point here.  You may like having heavily abstracted code, I like my users to have a faster page load.  Think of it this way: would you like *my* life easier, or would you like Stack Overflow to load faster?  As for switching, switching occurs so rarely (*if* ever) it's likely many versions ahead on the underlying library, which means your abstraction layer's way out of date and missing bits anyway...it's **more pain** to have it.

Comment: @NickCraver I mean adding a compile-time stage. Don't compile/inline at run-time! That would kill performance as you said.

Comment: @omouse - that's what I was referring to as well, it's still additional work to maintain, when you have a page that does/doesn't use a new method you now have to change your compilation...that's a world of hurt I wouldn't want to be in.  I just really fail to see the payoff here, it's less work to move libraries **if it ever happens**, and that's a very, *very* big if in the first place.  It's paying a very high insurance premium when the out of pocket is very cheap in comparison if anything ever happens, why would you want to do that?  It's positively baffling to me.

Comment: @NickCraver It's not less work, trust me, I'm working on a project right now that's switching from MooTools to jQuery and it's taking quite a while because all of the code relied on MooTools. We have to rewrite everything. With the extra layer, you wouldn't have to rewrite every page-specific javascript, just the middle layer that abstracts away the frameworks. It would be less work to have that middle layer in my particular case. Your results may vary I guess :p

Answer (score 3):

You will have to write adapters for each toolkit/library you might want to use for your framework, pretty much like [ExtJS/Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) has done (though theirs are probably not reusable).

Start out by mapping out what methods your adapter should have, it will act as your frameworks low level API.

Next step is to write an adapter for each possible toolkit/library. Some libraries will be hard to write adapters for like YUI, since they load code dynamically. You might have to compile a single .js file with needed functionality first.

Add a new toolkit/library, write a new adapter according to your mapping.

Answer (score 2):

This may have been a reasonable idea if the frameworks had equivalent functionality. Unfortunately they don't; they do different things, and they do them differently. There is cross-over between them, but your wrapper would miss out on a lot because you'd only be able to do your wrapping on stuff that was in both. You'd end up with the lowest common denominator; the worst of both worlds.

My advice is to take the time to learn both libraries - MooTools and JQuery are both very good libraries, and it's good to know them both. Even if you then only use one of them in your project, you will at least be able to make an informed choice before you start.

Comment: This is NOT true. There are various ways to 'fill in the gaps' that either may have. At one point you may apply the interface of a proprietary extention, at another point the base - library may have that covered. This is just ONE example. In the end, Coupling causes all kinds of headaches you don't want to deal with.